# Languages Without "To" And "From"

Tags: semantics, natural-semantic-metalanguage

I've been trying to construct sentences using only Semantic Primes (i.e., from the Natural Semantic Metalanguage). However, I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to do so without "to" and "from". For example, how might a language say something like, "I move from this place to this place" without using using "to" and "from" and without changing the fundamental meaning of the sentence?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about the Natural Semantic Metalanguage?

Comment: Yes, NSM & Semantic Primes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

American Sign Language doesn't use "to" and "from". Instead, you would sign something along the lines of "PAST, I live Orlando. LAST-YEAR, I move Seattle." The word for "move" is directional, meaning that you would move your hands in the direction from Orlando to Seattle - or, northwest. So you might argue that "move" is more literally "move-to", but there still is no specific word for "to" in ASL.

Comment: Swahili is also like that.

Comment: Really? That's fascinating.

Comment: Yes. :) [For example](https://translate.google.com/#en/sw/I%20went%20to%20Nairobi), "I went to Nairobi" is _Nilikwenda Nairobi_ - 1pSG.PAST.go Nairobi. No preposition, no case.

Comment: That's really interesting. Thanks! Also, are you from Kenya? My sister is from Kampala!

Comment: No, I'm from Ukraine. :)

Comment: Oh, ok. How come you know so much about Swahili?

Comment: I learned some Swahili. Every primary textbook has what I wrote here.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is a normal phenomenon in languages with **noun cases**.

Namely, [**Lative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lative_case) case (`LAT`) is used to denote *movement toward* an object, while
[**Ablative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablative_case) case (`ABL`) denotes *movement from* an object.

So basically, in these languages your example sentence would be formed,

> I move A-`ABL` B-`LAT`

The Ablative is much more widespread among the Indo-European languages, probably because it was one of the noun cases found in Sanskrit.

Note, however, that some languages still use particles along with certain noun cases, so it may not be a clear "without *"to"* and *"from"*.

**More than that!** Some languages differ the *movement toward* an object (Lative) from *movement into* an object (Illative) or *movement onto/under* an object (Sublative),
and also a similar distinction with *movement away from* (Ablative) and *movement from inside* an object (Elative).

See the full list of noun cases for [movement from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_grammatical_cases#Motion_from) and [movement to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_grammatical_cases#Motion_to) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Very informative, but Semantic Primes take into account casing. Molly's answer seems to cover it by referring to date.

Comment: @jamiestroud69 Well, since movement is something that "exists", languages will have ways to express it. If Semantic Primes takes into account all possible ways to express "to-fromness", then no, no languages will lack "to-fromness". They may rely on preopositons (he moved to London from Cambridge), case (he moved Londonto Cambridgefrom), word order (he Cambrige moved London), verbal flexion (he Cambridge was, London is), adverbs (he London now, Cambridge before), different verbs (he London came Cambridge vs he London went Cambridge), etc. So which of these count as "without to and from?"

Comment: Just incidentally, @LuísHenrique , it’s somewhat funny that you presuppose that if something exists than languages will express it... I think you got it backwards, rather “if a language expresses it, than the thing or phenomena is meaningful” (for those speakers) <let’s leave existence out of it — ontology isn’t part of linguistics!>

Comment: @Teusz - thence "exists" between quote marks.